# Display php echo in another html file

Tags: php, html

I have a php file with the following code:

```
echo($x);
```

Which simply prints

```
5.0
```

How would I display this value in a html file?

Comment: What do you mean: _"in a linked HTML file"?_

Comment: I deleted the 'linked'. What I meant was that if I had both the php file and the html file on the same server, how would I get them to talk to each other.

Comment: You've already displayed it! haven't you?!!

Comment: Yes, but if I wish to create a html file to collect the output from multiple php scripts, so simply printing from a php file won't do.

Comment: So, you want to modify the contents of an existing HTML file using the output of a PHP script; don't you?!

Comment: Exactly, that's right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90490/discussion-between-ttct-and-someone).

Comment: This will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635646/pass-variable-from-php-to-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any HTML manipulation APIs, like `DOMDocument` class. But, just to get you started, I assume you have a very simple HTML file:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

And you want to put the value of the `$x` variable inside the `<body>` tag using a `<div>` tag; simply:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$HTML_file = "paht/to/your/file.html";
$dom->loadHTMLFile($HTML_file);

// To get the <body> tag in the HTML file
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    
$body = $xpath->query('//body')->item(0);

// Insert some tags inside the <body> tag
$x = 5;
$element = $dom->createElement('div', $x);
$body->appendChild($element);

// overwrites to the same file
$dom->saveHTMLFile($HTML_file);
?>
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am binding my html file properly as nothing shows up. Could you give me some tips on how to debug? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Also, should I change '//body' to something else?

Comment: @ttct Nothing is supposed to be showed, The script modifies the example HTML file; After the script execution, the sample file should be modified having a `<div>` inside the `<body>` tag which has the content of the `$x` variable. Also, the `'//body'` is just an [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) expression to select the `<body>` tag in the provided example; The code is just a simple example to get you started :)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @ttct If it helps, please consider [accepting it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Yes, I did earlier but I don't think it was registered! Thanks again